# Where are the ancient artifacts in Eufloria?

Tags: ps3, eufloria

The Playstation 3 version of *Eufloria* adds "ancient artifacts" to some asteroids, which you must zoom in to find.

Are these artifacts on fixed asteroids in fixed levels, or are they randomly distributed?

If their level is fixed, what missions can they be found in, and if not randomly placed, on which asteroids? (To avoid further spoilers, I'd recommend identifying the levels by number rather than name, e.g. I believe I found the first artifact in 1-3.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artifacts are indeed fixed on certain levels, but I'm not sure about the specific asteroids - I would guess that they are randomly distributed.

Levels can contain 0 to 2 artifacts, here’s a list of all levels containing artifacts totaling up to 30:

> Level names omitted to prevent spoilers :)
>
> - Level 04: Ovoid 7
> - Level 05: Cubos, Q-Plane
> - Level 06: Bolian Radio
> - Level 07: Celestia Nest
> - Level 08: Amberous, Gersical Void
> - Level 09: Antropian Trap
> - Level 10: Micro Nautilus, Gliesian Mirror
> - Level 11: Geres Cloud Horn, Grower Husk
> - Level 12: Cache 13
> - Level 13: Cache 14
> - Level 14: Auto Vac, Iron Baloon
> - Level 15: Flux Calendar
> - Level 16: Fear Flower
> - Level 17: The Twins
> - Level 18: Guardian
> - Level 19: The Versuvia Tablet, False Witness
> - Level 20: Companions
> - Level 21: The individual
> - Level 22: Zotropic Enhancer, Gravitonastus
> - Level 23: Sensoric Antenna, Protoflora
> - Level 24: Mimic
> - Level 25: ?